# Data are not displayed althought the request is valid

Tags: angular, typescript, httpclient

I have a microservice and an angular web page that looks like

```
export class FilpComponent implements OnInit {
  flipped = false;
  word: MetaWord;

  flipIt() {
    this.flipped = !this.flipped;
  }

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver, private  metaWordService: MetaWordService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.metaWordService.read('laufen').subscribe(
      (data: MetaWord) => {
        this.word = data;
// this outputs undefined
        console.log(this.word.word);
      });
  }

  getSences(): Sens[] {
    return this.word.senses;
  }
}
```

and the Template looks like

```
<ng-container *ngIf="word !== undefined">
  <div>{{word.word}}</div>
</ng-container>
```

the request is sent properly and I can display the Data in Chrome DevTools. But the output of the subscribe is undefined.

This is the Output of `console.log(data)` or `console.log(word)`
[image]

UPDATE: Thanks to Nicholas K it does work now but I have the same problem here

the method getWords() return a populated object of type word. Object word would now have different senses. I want to show the different senses as divs as follows:

```
<div *ngFor="let word of getWords()">
  <div id="player" class="player" [class.voted]="flipped">
    <div class="front">
      <div class="grid-container">
        <h1 class="mat-h1">Dashboard</h1>
        <h1 class="mat-h1">{{word.word}}</h1>
        <div *ngFor="let example of word.senses">
          <div> here is an example of the word : {{example.sense}}</div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the word object is populated with data, but I expect to see multiple divs

The code of read in backend service is

```
return this.httpClient.get<MetaWord[]>(`${environment.words.baseUrl}/${term}`);
```

when I wirte a test method like this

```
  public print(){
    this.wordList.forEach(word=>{
      console.log(word.senses.length);
    })
  }
```

and call it after the data has been called from the backend service, then i get the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

It is somehow not correctly parsing the data to my object

Comment: And what does `console.log(this.word)` print?

Comment: Did you try to `console.log(data)` ?

Comment: `data` is an array, you need to access an index first. For eg: `this.data[0].word`

Comment: data is an Object of type metaword

Answer (score 2):

`data` is an array, you need to access an index first to reach the desired object.

For eg:

`console.log(this.data[0].word);`

---

Make the following change:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.metaWordService.read('laufen').subscribe(
      (data: MetaWord[]) => {
        // access via an index
        console.log(this.data[0].word);
      });
 }
```

assuming that your model `MetaWord` has been defined according to the response present in the question.

Comment: No. It is an array of `MetaWord`. It should be written as follows: `...subscribe(data: MetaWord[]) => { console.log(this.data[0].word); }`

Comment: thank you Nicholas K. I have updated the question, because of the same issue in the template

Comment: You're welcome. Can you elaborate on '*expect multiple divs*'? You should be assigning the response to an array for eg, `words = this.data`. Now in the template you need to iterate over *this* array `*ngFor="let content of words`.

Comment: Also, you'll need to share the code for `getWords()`.

Comment: Still don't see what `getWords()` returns.

Comment: it return this   public getWords(): MetaWord[] {
    return this.wordList;
  }

Comment: What are the contents of `this.wordList`?

Comment: the content is an array of objects of type metaword. In (DevTools -Network) I can see the values, but in the console an error occured, because of undefined

Comment: Share the json response as text and not as an image, as I can't see the entire structure.